# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Projection

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, servlets

Good Morning, please i don't know how to resolve that exception, i'm using ApcheTomcat 7 under eclipse and that exception is thrown everytime i run my servlet, here's my servlet for more clarity:

```
package servlets;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
 import dao.*;

@WebServlet("/AdminServlt")
public class AdminServlt extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
CarHome carDao;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
    carDao = new CarHome();
    }

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    populateAdminView(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

  public void populateAdminView(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    ArrayList productsList = (ArrayList) carDao.extractAdminAttributes();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("product_list",productsList);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Admin.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}

}
```

and here's `CarHome.java`

```
package dao;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;  
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.LockMode;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.*;
import entity.*;

    public class CarHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CarHome.class);

private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();


public List extractAdminAttributes() {
    log.debug("Extracting car attributes for administrator view");
    try {
        ArrayList results = (ArrayList) sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria("pojo.Car")
                .setProjection(
                        Projections.projectionList()
                                .add(Projections.property("carDesc"))
                                .add(Projections.property("price"))
                                .add(Projections.property("quantity")));

        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("find by admin view failed");
        throw re;
    }
  }
  }
```

here's the stacktrace of the exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.criterion.Projection
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
servlets.AdminServlt.init(AdminServlt.java:31)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted complete code? What is the business method? Why aren't you adding anything to the session's attributes?

Comment: an edit has been made

Comment: Show us `carDao.extractAdminAttributes()`. The problem should be in there.

Comment: If the class isn't found, the class isn't found: you're missing a library or a transitive dependency. Please include only the code in question.

Comment: What is your build tool? Are there any conflicting (old) versions of hibernate jars in your LIB folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved my problem it was very simple, the main reason is that the hibernate.cor.jar file wasn't in the lib folder under the web-content of the application when i put it there it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but in my case i re-ordered the hibernate-cor.jar on the top using eclipse

chose the project --> right click -->build path -->order tab -->chose the hibernate-cor.jar click top